# Datatable column width

Tags: datatable, width

I am having problem with datatable. Its width is too much in some columns and in some columns it is adding line breaks please have a look at attached image.

Any help will be appreciated.

[image]

Comment: it's not really a database question as much as some front end to a database question. as you mention neither the database nor the front end you're using, how can you expect an answer?

Comment: Yes I agree its not a database question its DATATABLE question. as you can see I mentioned DATATABLE not database.

Answer (score 0):

sorry about that chief, here's an example of how to set column width https://datatables.net/extensions/fixedcolumns/examples/initialisation/size_fluid.html